# How to map an interger key to an @ManyToOne object within the same @Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to have an optional `integer` column map to a `@ManyToOne` object at the same time?

Table:

`id,name,catalogid`

Accordingly the class:

```
@Entity
class MyTable {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;

    private Integer catalogId;  

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColum(name = "catalogId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_catalog"), nullable=true)
    private MyCatalog catalog;
}

@Entity
class MyCatalog {
    @Id
    private int catalogId;

    //some more fields...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "catalog")
    private Set<MyTable> mytables;
}
```

When I create that object, I know the `catalogid` already, but the foreign mapped table does not yet have content for the `catalogid`.

Question: is it possible to define the `@ManyToOne` optional? Thus, set the catalogid value, but only let hibernate create the object if it can be linked to the foreign table?

Comment: Maybe you can achieve this by making the @JoinColumn(nullable=true). This way the relation is not mandatory.

Comment: I tried, but did not work.

Comment: How can you know the ID of something that doesn't exist? That is bad database design. There should be a foreign key constraint on the catalog ID. What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: I have several data files that are imported into the database. The `catalogId` is known inside these files. BUT only the id is contained, not the catalog data. The catalog data itself is later loaded dynamically. Thus, I know the fix catalogid beforehand, even though the data for these catalogs does not exists yet (but may in future).

Comment: Why don't you load the catalogs first. That would allow checking that the catalog indeed exists when importing an item from the data file. Or at least, use two columns: one named future_catalog_id (for example), stored as an int in the entity, and another one named catalog_id, and stored as a ManyToOne in the entity, with a foreign key in the DB. That way, when you finally import the catalog, you can find all the items with the corresponding future_catalog_id, and if you end up never loading the catalog, you don't have invalid ManyToOne associations.

Comment: I cannot load the catalogs first, as they are lazy loaded on request only. Thus I always end up having potentially invalid `catalogIds`. Also, `MyTable ` entries might get deleted and `catalogs` should be retained. So I cannot have a tight coupling between them, anyhow I'd like mytable `@Entity` to having an optional `@ManyToOne` reference to that catalog so that I don't have to issue manual selects then I select that entity. Isn't that possible?

Comment: If they are lazy-loaded on request, and you have a request to insert a MyTable that needs a catalog, then lazy-load the catalog at this moment. Anyway, what you want is not an association with an entity. What you want is a loose reference to something that could or could not exist. So store it that way.